# How to call ajax from a javascript function on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written this function for calling a php script but its not working

```
function finalfun(id) {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        url: '/delete.php',
        method: 'POST', // or GET
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

This my php script delete.php

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
     echo ($_POST['id']);
     }
    else
    {
     echo "Id not found";
     }
     ?>
```

I have wriiten the finalfun() in .php file so is this a problem

Comment: `data: {'id':id},` is enough

Comment: `data: {id: id},` do it like this

Comment: Explain the term ***Not Working***

Comment: Change the url from `url: '/delete.php',` to `url: 'delete.php',`

Comment: The php script is not getting called

Comment: have tried changing the url but the script is not getting called

Comment: If delete.php in root folder then use   `./delete.php`  and if some another folder named   test then write   `./test/delete.php`  then try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.html:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
            finalfun(5);
        function finalfun(id) {
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    'id': id
                },
                url: 'delete.php',
                method: 'POST', // or GET
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }

        </script>
```

delete.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```

Comment: there were two errors 1:function not properly closed 2:delete.php having '/'

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with your `id`, you doing `id=`, just do

```
function finalfun(id) {

  $.ajax({
    data: {
      'id': id
    },
    url: '/delete.php',
    method: 'POST', // or GET
    success: function (msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Try changing the `URL` from `/delete.php` to just `delete.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: and also add jquery library file in your page.

```
function finalfun(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // use here type instead of method
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script >
         function show() {
        var id = $("select[name=box1]").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userviewcarajaxall.php',
            type: 'POST',

            data: {box1: id},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#model").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
```

call the function using onclick